# Why doesn't the loop here end 1 iteration sooner?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've been getting into python with Codecademy and now reviewing and practicing some more with LearnStreet. This held me back - the following code:

```
def run():
    count = 1
    while count <= 10:
        print count        
        count += 1
    return count
print run()
```

returns all numbers from 1 to 11. I thought it should return all numbers from 1 to **10**. Why does the loop print when `count == 11` ? The while states to execute the block only as long as the count is not greater than 10.

Comment: Well, it says greater or equal to. So if the count is at 10, it still goes in to your while making it an 11.

Comment: @berentrom no. 11 is greater than 10 : when count equals 11, the loop is not executed

Comment: Oh yeah I saw it wrong, count += is defined after the print.

Answer (score 8):

The loop doesn't print 11. `print run()` does, because the function `run()` returns 11.

Comment: Hmm... You seem to have stated this more succinctly than me.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

You print `count`, then you increment it, then you check for the value in the `while` statement.  This will print all the numbers up to 10, but leave `count`'s value at 11.  After that, you *return* `count` from the function and print the return value which is `11`.

Answer (score 1):

The run function prints everything from 1 to 10, and returns 11. The print statement (that invoked the run() function) prints the return value --- which is 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation inline:

```
def run():
    count = 1
    while count <= 10:
        print count    # Will print numbers from 1, to 10, inclusively.
        count += 1     # Will increment count
    return count
print run()            # Will print the value returned, which is 11
```

The loop indeed prints values in the range [1, 10], but returns the last value of `count`, which is 11, to be printed by the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your loop, count = 11 and then your "run" function returns it.

So when you execute `print run()`, it prints 11 :)

Answer (score 0):

No it should return 11. The loop continues because it has the `<=` operator. When  count is equal to 10 the loop runs one more time adding 1 and making it 11. That when the loop exits. If you want it to return 10 use the `<` operator instead

Comment: That's not the right answer. The loop itself prints numbers from 1 to 10 (when count is equal to 11, the loop body is not executed and the number 11 is not printed). The right answer is provided by mgilson.